# How does function ListPlot3D color according to the values (or specified value) in the fourth column?

Tags: plotting

I want to plot the data from the second to the fourth columns and color them according to the data in the fifth column:

```
data = {{1., 74., 781., 5., 4.}, {2., 1373., 731., 11., 4.}, {3., 
   1321., 1791., 28., 4.}, {4., 0., 1787., 4., 2.}, {5., 1049., 2127.,
    12., 4.}, {6., 1647., 2728., 6., 2.}, {7., 2883., 3617., 15., 
   4.}, {8., 2383., 3692., 7., 2.}, {9., 2708., 2295., 22., 4.}, {10.,
    2933., 1767., 7., 4.}, {11., 4233., 895., 6., 5.}, {12., 4043., 
   1895., 14., 1.}, {13., 2427., 3971., 2., 1.}, {14., 3526., 4357., 
   7., 4.}, {15., 5062., 4339., 5., 4.}, {16., 4777., 4897., 8., 
   1.}, {17., 5868., 4904., 16., 4.}, {18., 6534., 5641., 6., 
   1.}, {19., 5481., 6004., 0., 4.}, {20., 4592., 4603., 6., 
   1.}, {21., 2486., 5999., 2., 1.}, {22., 3299., 6018., 4., 
   4.}, {23., 3573., 6213., 5., 1.}, {24., 4741., 6434., 5., 5.}};

ListPointPlot3D[data[[All, 2 ;; All]], ColorFunctionScaling -> True, 
 ColorFunction -> (Hue[#4] &), PlotRange -> Full]
```

But the above graph cannot be dyed according to the fifth column data. What should I do?

Answer (score 3):

```
ListPointPlot3D[List /@ data[[All, 2 ;; 4]], 
 PlotStyle -> (Hue /@ Rescale[data[[All, 5]]])]
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can wrap each data point `with` Style`:

```
data2 = data;
data2[[All, 5]] = Rescale[data2[[All, 5]]];

ListPointPlot3D[Style[#[[2 ;; 4]], Hue@#[[5]]] & /@ data2]
```

[image]

As b3m2a1 suggested in comments, using `Graphics3D` and styling the point primitives with the option `VertexColors` would be more efficient:

```
Graphics3D[GraphicsComplex[data[[All, 2 ;; 4]], 
  {PointSize[Large], 
   Point[Range[Length@data], VertexColors -> (Hue /@ Rescale[data[[All, 5]]])]}], 
 BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1/2}, Axes -> True]
```

[image]

You might find [`BubbleChart3D`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BubbleChart3D.html) convenient:

```
BubbleChart3D[data[[All, 2 ;;]], ColorFunction -> (Hue[#4] &), 
 BubbleSizes -> {.05, .05}, Boxed -> True, FaceGrids -> None]
```

[image]

You can make the output look like the output from `ListPointPlot3D` using the option `ChartElementFunction`:

```
BubbleChart3D[data[[All, 2 ;;]], ColorFunction -> (Hue[#4] &), 
 ChartElementFunction -> ({PointSize[Large], Point[Mean /@ #]} &), 
 Boxed -> True, FaceGrids -> None, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1/2}]
```

[image]

Comment: Might be worth also pointing out that neither of these will perform particularly well and a better approach tends to be constructing something like `Point[..., VertexColors->...]`

Comment: @b3m2a1, thank you; very good point. I updated with your suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

The first element in the data just a order number, we can remove it. And we use label to demonstrate the last value.

```
data = {{1., 74., 781., 5., 4.}, {2., 1373., 731., 11., 4.}, {3., 
    1321., 1791., 28., 4.}, {4., 0., 1787., 4., 2.}, {5., 1049., 
    2127., 12., 4.}, {6., 1647., 2728., 6., 2.}, {7., 2883., 3617., 
    15., 4.}, {8., 2383., 3692., 7., 2.}, {9., 2708., 2295., 22., 
    4.}, {10., 2933., 1767., 7., 4.}, {11., 4233., 895., 6., 
    5.}, {12., 4043., 1895., 14., 1.}, {13., 2427., 3971., 2., 
    1.}, {14., 3526., 4357., 7., 4.}, {15., 5062., 4339., 5., 
    4.}, {16., 4777., 4897., 8., 1.}, {17., 5868., 4904., 16., 
    4.}, {18., 6534., 5641., 6., 1.}, {19., 5481., 6004., 0., 
    4.}, {20., 4592., 4603., 6., 1.}, {21., 2486., 5999., 2., 
    1.}, {22., 3299., 6018., 4., 4.}, {23., 3573., 6213., 5., 
    1.}, {24., 4741., 6434., 5., 5.}};
ListPointPlot3D[data[[All, 2 ;; 4]] -> data[[All, 5]], 
 PlotStyle -> Directive[PointSize[Medium], Red], 
 LabelingFunction -> Above, PlotStyle -> PointSize[Medium], 
 LabelStyle -> Cyan, TicksStyle -> Orange]
```

[image]